# macOS Mission Control strange behavior on Sierra

Tags: macos, dock, desktop, bug, mission-control

I have noticed a bug in Mission Control on macOS Sierra (10.12.2).

Here's a GIF to reproduce the bug:

[image]

It happens when I try to open an app from the Dock, while I'm showing the Desktop: the app doesn't open, windows come back in place, then if I toggle Mission Control, the app I clicked before opens (or get in front if already opened).

Step by step, as shown in GIF:

1. Show Desktop
2. Click on any app in the Dock
3. App won't open, windows come back in place instead
4. Open Mission control
5. Exit Mission control: previously clicked app opens

Is anyone experiencing the same?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the bug with your instructions. (mid-2014 rMBP, macOS 10.12.2) I would recommend that you [report it to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to alert them of the bug.

Comment: Thanks, I already reported it to Apple. I also started another discussion on their official support forum, where other users confirmed the same behavior: https://discussions.apple.com/message/31173836

Comment: This is fixed on Sierra 10.12.4